# ggplot2: area chart with categorical x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data frame `language.tickets` with two variables: `language` and `tickets`:

```
             language tickets
1             chinese     474
2               czech     451
3               dutch    6802
4             english   29068
5              french    4133
6              german    2587
7             italian    2210
8            japanese    1782
9              korean    4029
10              other   40448
11             polish    1149
12         portuguese   11157
13            russian    7546
14            spanish   32262
15            swedish    1615
```

I want to create an area chart having the `language` on the x axis and number of `tickets` in the y axis. I know that the best way would be to make a bar chart, but I want to superimpose another bar chart with this area chart.

Currently I'm trying this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=language.tickets, aes(x=language, y=tickets)) +
  geom_area()
```

This shows an empty chart. If I use `geom_area(stat="identity")` creates the bar chart correctly, how can I make an area chart instead?

Comment: I think that the `x` aesthetic must be numeric in `geom_area()` so you can't use it in your example.

Comment: You'd need to add a `group` aesthetic to connect the discrete values, e.g. `ggplot(data = language.tickets, aes(x = language, y = tickets, group = 1)) +
  geom_area()`. A bar chart (`geom_col` here) seems like it would make more sense, though.

Comment: @alistaire Perfect, that works. I was missing the group=1. That solved it. Thanks!